# Sphere parameter optimization: how would I approach it?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I am looking to construct a program that takes, as input, 576 [x, y, z] points as well as 576 corresponding distance values.

I want to find the [x, y, z, radius] parameters of a sphere such that the distance from each of the input points to the surface of the sphere matches as closely as possible to the corresponding distance value.

I tried constructing a neural network in TensorFlow, but after consideration, it seems like this kind of structure is not well-suited to this problem.

What is a good structure or approach to this problem and how would I implement it?

Thanks!

edit: When I refer to corresponding distance value, this means the value from the input distance array that matches with the given point (already in order). The distance parameter states how far away we know each point to be from the surface of the sphere. I am trying to fit the points with another set of points, but I can only represent the points to be fitted to as a certain distance away from a sphere, thus I am trying to select the position of the center and the radius of said sphere.

---

update: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CClOK.jpg

I was able to calculate some gradients based on a mean-squared error loss function for each point. This allowed me to to create the bit of pseudocode in the first picture which will form the basis of my program.

Comment: The phrase "the distance from each of the input points to the surface of the sphere matches as closely as possible to the corresponding distance value" is not specific enough.  What does the "distance value" actually measure, and what does "matches as closely as possible" mean?  Are you looking for the sphere that most closely fits the point set?

Comment: Potentially related: [Advent of Code 2018 Day 23](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/a8s17l/2018_day_23_solutions/). Spoilers if you haven't done the puzzle...

Comment: NNs are totally unsuitable for this task. A simple iterative solver can probably give you a good approximate solution: pick a random start point, then see in which direction the point cloud pulls this centroid point (that should be a matter of simple vector addition). The tricky point is just to determine the pull strength from the centroid–cloudpoint vector. If calculating pull strength is too difficult, just define a loss function and do a random walk. Run that algorithm a couple of times with different start points, and choose the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call *c*<sub>i</sub>  the i-th input point in *R*³, *d*<sub>i</sub> the i-th distance in *R*, and *c* and *r* the center and radius of the sphere you are looking for.

I guess what you want to minimize here is the real-valued function

> f(c,r)=Sum<sub>i=1,...,576</sub>(|dist(*c*<sub>i</sub> - c) - *d*<sub>i</sub> - *r*|²)

(the term inside the sum is the square of the distance of the surfaces of the sphere (*c*,*r*) from the sphere (*c*<sub>i</sub>,*d*<sub>i</sub>). Please double check if that is really what you mean *"matching as closely as possible to the corresponding distance"*, your verbal description is a little bit ambigous.

This is an *unconstrained nonlinear optimization problem*, and you will find several numerical algorithms to solve such problems when you just google those terms.

One of the most simple algorithms for this is called [Gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). There are two obstacles here:

- calculation of the partial derivations of `f` (can be solved either analytical or by approximation through difference quotients)
- finding a good starting point for the iteration

I leave the details as an exercise to you, since a full-blown answer would take a lot more time for me than I have to spare for now, and the format of this Q&A site is not well suited for this.

You can implement such an algorithm using any programming language you like, but you will probably need some support for matrix/vector calculus. Matlab (or its free clone "Octave") is a popular framework for such kind of tasks.

Final note: I doubt that "machine learning" is a suitable approach for solving classic, analytical optimization problems. Maybe it can be done, but as a colleague once said to me: one can also "put on their trousers using pliers".